# Laravel eager load an order by related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have something like `::with(['code', 'company', 'room'])` and I want to order by a column of the 'codes' table, but it does not work like `orderBy('codes.created_at', 'ASC')`, it works only with `orderByDesc` which is slow, for 17k records I get a load of 50 seconds.

I have tried to join

```
::select('contact_forms.*')->join('codes', 'codes.form_id', '=', 'contact_forms.id')
```

Now the ordering works like `orderBy('codes.created_at', 'ASC')` but it also slows the normal ones, I loose the eager loading, the count takes too much, from 10 statements and 30ms, that eager loading helped with, it goes to 70 statements and 220 ms, this on 20 per page just.
If I add ->join on the other 2 tables, companies and rooms, it takes even longer, not less, so that's not how eager loading works.
I've seen it does select with IN
`` select * from `codes` where `codes`.`form_id` in (22804, 22805, 22806, 22807, 22808, 22809, 22810, 22811, 22812, 22813, 22814, 22815, 22816, 22817, 22818, 22819, 22820, 22821, 22822, 22823) `` instead of 20 statement like `` select * from `codes` where `codes`.`form_id` = 22823 and `codes`.`form_id` is not null limit 1 ``

Also `select count(*) as aggregate from` takes too much, now it joins, when using eager load it would not and it was much faster.

Is there any way I can solve this? Or I should just let it be slower? Thing is I really loved how faster it's with eager load on all searches and all sorting beside the one in the other table, but it's too insane from 20ms to 60s.

You can see some tests [here](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel)

// Edit: I "patched" it so to say, I made it join only when sorting that column, otherwise don't, so now when sorting that column is between 40ms and 90ms

Answer (score 1):

Check 2 solutions:

1. Index the "created_at" column on the "codes" table
2. Use a subquery to sort the results

```php
ContactForm::with(['code', 'company', 'room'])
->orderBy(
DB::raw('(SELECT created_at FROM codes WHERE form_id = contact_forms.id ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1)'),
'ASC'
);
```